# Convert time from EST to UTC in Excel

Tags: excel

I have an EST timezone (ex: `02-DEC-19 09.30.24.301000000 PM`) and I want to convert it to UTC using Excel functions.

I have tried `(C2+time(5,0,0))` and nothing happens

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-time-to-time-zone

Answer (score 1):

the date is text and needs to be parsed.  Excel does can not see the `.` as deliniation of time parts.  They need to be changed to `:`.  Then add the time. Use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",":",1),".",":",1)+TIME(5,0,0)
```

then you can format the output any way you want.

[image]